# How to get IAM/service account used by juicefs to access GCS in GKE?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm using a [juicefs-csi](https://github.com/juicedata/juicefs-csi-driver) in GKE. I use postgre as meta-store and GCS as storage. The corresponding setting is as follow:

```yaml
node:
  # ...
  storageClasses:
    - name: juicefs-sc
      enabled: true
      reclaimPolicy: Retain
      backend:
        name: juicefs
        metaurl: postgres://user:password@my-ec2-where-postgre-installed.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/the-database?sslmode=disable
        storage: gs
        bucket: gs://my-bucket
   # ...
```

According to [this](https://juicefs.com/docs/community/how_to_setup_object_storage/#google-cloud-storage) documentation, I don't have to specify access key/secret (like in S3).

But unfortunately, whenever I try to write anything to the mounted volume (with `juicefs-sc` storage class), I always get this error:

```
AccessDeniedException: 403 Caller does not have storage.objects.create access to the Google Cloud Storage object.
```

I believe it should be related to IAM role.

My question is, **how could I know which IAM user/service account is used by juicefs** to access GCS, so that I can assign a sufficient role to it?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Step by step:

- Download juicefs-csi helm chart
- Add values as described in the question, apply
- Create a pod that mount from PV with `juicefs-sc` storage class
- Try to read/write file to the mount point

Comment: Could you elaborate your actions/steps? You mention GCP but in metaurl you have aws. In GCP most popular autohorization option is to use proper `ServiceAccount`, more details [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started). Also in your docs you have link to options how to auth your request [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#examples). If you didn't create it means you are using default GCP SA which permissions depends on your project. You probably need to create SA with `Storage Object Creator` role.

Comment: One way to know the SA, would be to go to MENU> LOGGING> look for the permission denied error, expand the error and if you look for the principal email that should give you an indication of which SA is failing.

Comment: Hi @PjoterS sorry for miss-lead. My postgre db is hosted in ec2. Juicefs need "meta URL" to save the configuration/structure and "storage" to save the real object. Thank you for the pointers.

Comment: Hy @danyL Definitely going to need that. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I misunderstood you at the beginning.

When you are creating `GKE` cluster you can specify which GCP `Service Account` will be used by this cluster, like below:
[image]

By `Default` it's `Compute Engine default service account` (71025XXXXXX-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com) which is lack of a few Cloud Product permissions (like `Cloud Storage`, it has `Read Only`). It's even described in this message.

[image]

If you want to check which `Service Account` was set by default to VM, you could do this via

Compute Engine > VM Instances > Choose one of the VMs from this cluster > In details find `API and identity management`

[image]

So You have like 3 options to solve this issue:

**1. During Cluster creation**

In `Node Pools` > `Security`, you have `Access scopes` where you can add some additional permissions.

- `Allow full access to all Cloud APIs` to allow access for all listed Cloud APIs
- `Set access for each API`

[image]

In your case you could just use `Set access for each API` and change `Storage` to `Full`.

**2. Set permissions with a Service Account**
You would need to create a new `Service Account` and provide proper permissions for `Compute Engine` and `Storage`. More details about how to create `SA` you can find in [Creating and managing service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts).

**3. Use Workload Identity**

> Workload Identity on your Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) clusters. Workload Identity allows workloads in your GKE clusters to impersonate Identity and Access Management (IAM) service accounts to access Google Cloud services.

For more details you should check [Using Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity).

**Useful links**

- [Configuring Velero](https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero-plugin-for-gcp#option-1-set-permissions-with-a-service-account) - Velero is software for backup and restore, however steps 2 and 3 are mentioned there. You would just need to adjust commands/permissions to your scenario.
- [Authenticating to Google Cloud with service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform)

Comment: I finally used workload identity. Thanks for the elaborated answer